# I'm not getting the image from the url using Glide

Tags: java, android, try-catch, android-glide

here is the code which I tried.
I'm not getting the image in bmp using Glide and when I pass the null bmp in the method which converts the image to the byte[] then the error occurs.
new AsyncTask() {

```
        @Override
        protected byte[] doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            Looper.prepare();
            byte[] byteimage = new byte[0];
            Bitmap bmp1;
            try {
                bmp= Glide.with(specificrecipe.this)//bmp is global
                        .load(url2img)
                        .asBitmap()
                        .into(100,100)
                        .get();
            byteimage=getBytes(bmp);//here I'm not getting the image in bmp
                //ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                //bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);//null object refrence -> bmp
                //byteimage=stream.toByteArray();
                //byteimage1.add(0,byteimage);
                // initialize(bmp);
            }catch (final ExecutionException e){e.printStackTrace();}
            catch (final InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}
            return byteimage;
        }

        //@Override
        //protected void onPostExecute(byte[] Bytearray){
        //byteimage1=Bytearray;
         //}
    }.execute();
```

Comment: If you want to convert into bitmap . Glide lib will do it for you.

Comment: see after passing the URL to the Glide I'm not receiving the image in BMP null exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you

```
Bitmap theBitmap = Glide.
    with(this).
    load("http://....").
    asBitmap().
    into(100, 100). // Width and height
    get();
```

Comment: please suggest another way. I'm still not receiving the image from URL.

Answer (score 0):

//this is the way through which I get the image from URL even the glide is not working for saving the image from URL.

```
try {
       URL url = new URL(url2img);//url2img is a String
       bmp =BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
       //bmp is global variable  
}catch (IOException e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
    byteimage1=getBytes(bmp);
```